# Android: upload apk from android studio terminal to google drive account

Tags: android, drive

Can I generate APK and upload it to google drive using an android studio terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you can write a gradle script or use a gradle `TaskExecutionListener` to generate/listen to the apk and then upload it to a given google drive. As far as I know there are some Google Drive CLI clients so you just need to piece them together.
I don't know about any built-in solution for Android Studio if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't want a build-in solution in android studio, I justed to know if it is possible.
Thanks